# verificar valores repetidos en datatable jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo un formulario de la siguiente manera:

tengo cuatro inputs en HTMl en los cuales un usuario ingresa la  siguiente informacion personal: nombre, telefono, id personal y id empresarial, tanto el id empresarial como el personal son numeros unicos que son asignados a una unica persona por tanto no pueden haber dos personas con el mismo id (personal o empresarial).

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="inputText1" required>
        <input type="text" id="inputText2" required>
        <input type="text" id="inputText3" required>
        <input type="text" id="inputText4" required>
        <button type="button" id="submit" value="submitB">Guardar Registro</button>
    </div>

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            var nombre = $("#inputNombre").val();
                            var lastname = $("#inputTelefono").val();
                            var name = $("#inputIdP").val();
                            var country = $("#inputIdE").val();
```

junto con el formulario tengo un boton submit que ingresa la informacion a la base datos y luego en el mismo formulario se refresca un datatable jQuery con la informacion ingresada en la tabla correspondiente y todos los inputs se limpian a espera de nueva informacion que seguira la misma logica(todo funciona bien).

este es el codigo de mi tabla

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="myTable" style="width:100%; margin:0 auto;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombres</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>idP</th>
                <th>idE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

y el codigo con el que cargo el datatable

```
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                searching: false,
                paging: true,
                responsive: true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/home/loaddata",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                        { "data": "nombre", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                        { "data": "telefono", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                        { "data": "idP", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                        { "data": "idE", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                        { "defaultContent": "<button>editar</button>" }

                //{ "defaultContent": " <a href='#' id='select'>Modificar</a>  "}
                ],
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sEmptyTable": "No hay registros disponibles",
                    "sInfo": "Hay _TOTAL_ registros. Mostrando de (_START_ a _END_)",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Por favor espera - Cargando...",
                    "sSearch": "Filtro:",
                    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sLast": "Última página",
                        "sFirst": "Primera",
                        "sNext": "Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                    }
                } 
            });
```

Ahora bien, como lod dos id no pueden repetirse quisiera que si el usuario ha especificado en los inputs correspondientes uno (o ambos) id que ya existen en el datatatable se le avise la imposibilidad de ingresar el registro pero quisiera hacerlo utilizando jQuery y no hacer un viaje a la base de datos para verificar, sino que tome el valor de los inputs y me verifique con la informacion actualmente presentada en el jQuery datatable que no son id repetidos

Comment: Hola Pablo,...

Sería mejor que pegaras tu código para poder analizarlo.

Comment: Hola, modifique la pregunta mostrando el codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN CORTA:**

Si tenés los ids almacenados en un arreglo podrías hacer uso de la siguiente función que nos ofrece Jquery:

```
if ( jQuery.inArray( idIngresado, arreglo ) != -1 )
```

Sin necesidad de recorrer la datatable.

**SOLUCIÓN LARGA:**

Podrías asignarle una clase a los `th` para poder ver sus valores:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="myTable" style="width:100%; margin:0 auto;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombres</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th class="idsDeclarados">idP</th>
                <th>idE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Y después declarar una función en Javascript (usando Jquery) que devuelva `true` si encuentra el id, `false` en caso contrario:

```
function existeID(id) {
    $('.idsDeclarados').each(function () {
        if ( (this).html() == id)
            return true;
    });
    return false;
}
```

Espero haberte sido de ayuda.